# Read data from JSON file, add new data following data structure VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, io, json.net

Okay, So I have been trying to wrap my small head around this topic for some time now. All I want to do is:

1) Read all data from a .json file

2) Add data to the json file, while still following structure (Adding objects withing java somehow maybe?)

3) Save file back

I have figured out how to download json.net and add it to my project. I just have no clue how to use it.

I am a big noob at java and vb, so please don't reply with a bunch of unnecessary stuff that won't help. (Really irritated by this already :|)

I am writing this with a GUI, so no console stuff, as I seen from most of the sources on the interweb.

Things I have tried: Reading all lines and storing into var, array and or string.

```
Dim str() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\MCHCI_Profile.txt")
```

I got this from somewhere but threw and error of 1 dimensional array

```
Dim singleChar As Char
singleChar = str.Chars(14)
```

Somethings with streamreader and writer but not too much, as it confuses me.

```
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\MCHCI_Profile.txt")
            Do
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Loop Until sr.EndOfStream
        End Using
```

^This seemed to work, it added all the right data into combobox and kept json structure, but I don't know what to do with it.

**Final conclusion**

It seems like the only real way to do this is with json.net

So please let me know how to read data, add simple objects to it and save it back

Thank you !!!

Comment: but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @Code I made a new question that should let you understand my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690288/adding-new-property-to-json-object-using-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

As of now i don't get what actually you are trying to achieve. Let me assume that
1. You are accepting a text file content to a one dimensional array.
2. then you are selecting a single character from particular index from that array, isn't it?
this will achieve the first option without fail.

```
  Dim str() As String = File.ReadAllLines("D:\sample.txt")
```

if you want particular line of text then you can take it from the array by using the index value as like the following:

```
  Dim lineOfText As String = str(14)
```

if you want a single character from particular line of text then you can take it from the array by using the index value as like the following:

```
  Dim singleChar As Char=str(14).ToCharArray()(2)
```