# Adding new property to json object using VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

I'm trying to add a new property to an existing object from a json file. I would like to add a new profile being stored in a json file

Here is the json structure of the file.

[image]

You see, I need to go after: "profiles": { and add the stuff here, duplicate one of those profiles structure and paste it here with new data. ex. "NEW PROFILE NAME": {"name": "NEW PROFILE NAME", "lastVersionId": "VERSION ID"

Here is what I have so far, but don't know what to do with it, maybe you will understand

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader("C:\Launcher_Profiles.json")
        Dim jsonData As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        reader.Close()

        'At this point we have the json data in a string variable, parse it and enumerate  
        'each token in the parent "objects" and if it starts with realms we will add a new  
        'MinecraftData object to a list of MinecraftData objects  
        Dim allData As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData)

        Dim minecraftDataList As New List(Of ProfileData)

        For Each token As JToken In allData("objects")

            Dim prop As JProperty = token

            If prop.Name.StartsWith("profiles") Then
                minecraftDataList.Add(New ProfileData With {.ProfileName = prop.Name, .ProfileVersion = prop.Value("ProfileVersion"), .Size = prop.Value("size")})
            End If

        Next

        'Now you have all of the data in the minecraftDataList  
        For Each md As ProfileData In minecraftDataList
            Console.WriteLine(md.ProfileName)
            Console.WriteLine(md.ProfileVersion)
            Console.WriteLine(md.Size)
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Why dont you deserialize your JSON into the object you have created? You can use JSON.net library. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Comment: @kcbeard I am a big noob at programming, do you think you can explain it to me? All I want to do is get the text, add new stuff into the json, and save it back accordingly. I have been stuck with this for weeks.